# BigInteger equivalent for decimals in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, biginteger, bigdecimal

I thought big integer also works on decimals, but it doesnt. I need to print decimal with high precision, is there any decimal equivalent of BigInteger?

Comment: Is `decimal` high-precision enough?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types

Comment: Several hits on Nuget for [Rational](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=rational), several of which seem to build on top of BigInteger.

Comment: [`decimal` has a documented precision of 28-29 digits.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/numerics#floating-point-types) Do you really need more?

Comment: Might be fun to create one, but demand will be nowhere near has high as in Java because C# has a built-in decimal type. Most Java usage of BigDecimal is for not-so-big financial calculations.

Answer (score 2):

`System.Decimal` has 16 bytes and is the highest standard available:

`±1,0 x 10-28 to ±7,9228 x 1028`.

It seems that there is a `Java.Math` assembly to have `BigDecimal` :

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/java.math.bigdecimal

Else I found this:

[BigDecimal type in .NET](https://gist.github.com/nberardi/2667136)

[BigDecimal implementation in C#](https://github.com/CognitioConsulting/BigDecimal)

[Create BigDecimal Type in C#](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29090125/Create-BigDecimal-Type-in-C.html)